# UICollectionViewController not working in upgraded XCode 7 project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on a project that uses storyboards and was started in XCode 6 and has been upgraded to XCode 7.  I am trying to add a UICollectionViewController.  I get an exception on this line: `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UnsplashCollectionViewCell`

I have verified that the controller and cell are both assigned to my custom class in the storyboard, and that my reuse identifier is assigned to the cell and the same as the variable reuseIdentifier in my controller class.

About the only difference I can tell between a working UICollectionViewController and this project's is if I start a new project and add a UICollectionViewController I get the following in the Connections Inspector:
[image: Working - New Project]

However, the Connections Inspector in my broken project looks like:
[image: Not Working - Upgraded Project]

I'm not sure this is the problem, but I'm at a loss for what else it could be.

Crash log:

> Uncaught exception: could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier UnsplashCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

[image: Cell Inspectors]

Full Crash Log:

```
2016-03-14 10:34:55.027 PixelSquidTouch[86881:2845927] [Crashlytics] Version 3.4.1 (92)
2016-03-14 10:34:55.063 PixelSquidTouch[86881:]  App measurement v.1201000 started
2016-03-14 10:35:02.990 PixelSquidTouch[86881:2845927] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UICollectionView.m:3690
2016-03-14 10:35:03.013 PixelSquidTouch[86881:2845927] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:48): Uncaught exception: could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier UnsplashCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard
2016-03-14 10:35:08.054 PixelSquidTouch[86881:2845927] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier UnsplashCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c95ce65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ffb0deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c95ccca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010fa274de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010ddd04e9 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 2009
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ddd0945 -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 169
    6   PixelSquidTouch                     0x000000010b8d9e6a _TFC15PixelSquidTouch32UnsplashCollectionViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView22cellForItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 122
    7   PixelSquidTouch                     0x000000010b8d9f8f _TToFC15PixelSquidTouch32UnsplashCollectionViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView22cellForItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 79
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ddc05ba -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:] + 483
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ddc2ae0 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4431
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010ddc723b -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 247
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d6224a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f41759a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f40be70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f40bcee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f400475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f42dc0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010d596b47 _afterCACommitHandler + 174
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c888367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c8882d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c87df2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c87d828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011197cad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010d56b610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    24  PixelSquidTouch                     0x000000010b957aad main + 109
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110b5692d start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

[image: CollectionViewController hierarchy]

Comment: post the crash log or exception

Comment: the crashlog seems to be quite straightforward to me... what is the real issue here?

Answer (score 1):

So, you are trying to dequeue a cell but there is no cell with that ID. You need to open the cell in the storyboard or Xib and set the `UICollectionElementKindCell` ID to that id `UnsplashCell`

If you havent done the cell in the storyboard as a prototype cell, but are using a xib file, then you also need to register that cell with the tableview, so it knows about the cell type.

in your viewDidLoad:

```
let nibName = UINib(nibName: "UICollectionElementKindCell", bundle:nil)
self.tableView.registerNib(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UnsplashCell")
```

Update:

Look at the objects outlets etc. in the storyboard with the VC selected. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm doing this on the story board and I set Collection Reusable View Identifier to the same string as the reuseIdentifier I'm using in the call to dequeue - I'm assuming that is the same thing as UICollectionElementKindCell ID?  If not, can you tell me where to find that property?

Comment: Sadly, then, it must be something else that is wrong.  I've checked several times that the IDs are the same.  I still think it must be something to do with the conversion of the storyboard from XCode 6 to XCode 7.

Comment: You could post your storyboard? or a screenshot of the cell inspectors. I suspect that it could also be the type that has changed. Is the custom cell of the correct class type?

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this.  I can't share the storyboard, but I have some screenshots of the cell inspectors.  If I start a brand new project and set the classes and reuse identifier it works, it just doesn't work in this project.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it is trying to load UICollectionElementKindCell, and not the correct cell type. Could you paste the fill crash log please? You could also open the storyboard as code and look for UICollectionElementKindCell inside it.

Comment: Oh, and also set the outlet for the collection view, which is not set in your "broken" project, but is in your original

Comment: Updated with full crash log.  Prior to this run I connected the `collectionView` outlet with the `Collection View`.  I've tried it both ways and it doesn't seem to make a difference.  The difference between the working projects and my projects is that there is an outlet for `view` which is connected to the `Collection View`, but my project doesn't have that outlet (which I am assuming is an artifact of upgrading the storyboard from XCode 6 to XCode 7, but not sure).

Comment: "connect a prototype cell in a storyboard" - you need to connect the cell in the storyboard. Also, did you register the nib or class?

Comment: I'm possibly confused but assigning the custom class and the reuse identifier is the same thing as "connect a prototype cell in a storyboard", no?  I've tried registering the nib (and it says it can't be found).  I've tried registering the class, which actually gets me further - the dequeue call succeeds, however any IBOutlets I've defined in the cell are nil.  I've also read elsewhere that you EITHER use storyboards or you register the nib/class, but not both.

Comment: exactly, its one or the other. So, if the outlets are nil after registering, you need to connect the cell to the collectionviewCell in the storyboard. The side panel with all the subview on the left. cntrl click on the cell in that list, and I bet it has no outlets including the cell. You need to reconnect all the outlets and actions :(. I updated my answer with screenshot

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but I honestly think there is something wrong with the storyboard file itself.  They are connected correctly, they are named correctly.  

The cells image view is connected the the IBOutlet for the image view in my custom class.  And while that's `nil` when using registerClass, I don't think I should be using register class because everything is setup in the storyboard.

I may try and file a bug with Apple at this point unless someone knows a way to easily regenerate a storyboard without having to recreate the entire thing.

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, dont register the prototype cell. Did you try open the storyboard file as code format? You could then search for that cell type it is crashing on. - UICollectionElementKindCell , and check if it is that one for your cell, and replace the name etc. in code, then re-open the storyboard as the storyboard visual format

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with this same issue since upgrading to XCode 7 last week. In our case, we were disabling user interaction whenever we displayed an activity view:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Then, in a callback block we were re-enabling user interaction with this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Removing these calls resolved three out of four of these issues in our code; hopefully it can fix your issue as well. In any event, we haven't come up with a better approach as of yet.

Comment: Thanks.  We are not making those calls, so it seems not to be the same issue.  Hopefully we can both find a solution soon!